# Order of categorical x and y axis in bubble chart reversed? How to unreverse?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bubble-chart

This is the head of my data:

```
structure(list(asutus = c("Eesti Draamateater", "Eesti Draamateater", 
"Eesti Draamateater", "Eesti Noorsooteater", "Eesti Noorsooteater", 
"Eesti Noorsooteater", "Rahvusooper Estonia", "Rahvusooper Estonia", 
"Rakvere Teatrimaja", "Rakvere Teatrimaja", "Rakvere Teatrimaja", 
"Rakvere Teatrimaja", "Sakala Teatrimaja", "Vene Teater", "Vene Teater", 
"Vene Teater", "Vene Teater"), hoone_liik = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("teatrihoone", 
"ladu", "töökojad", "muu"), class = "factor"), hoone_suletud_netopind = c(2441.1, 
6004, 705.8, 672, 970.8, 3509, 2337.6, 12426.7, 973, 3307.4, 
4478, 446.6, 3220, 394.8, 281.5, 5873.9, 373.7)), row.names = c(NA, 
-17L), groups = structure(list(asutus = c("Eesti Draamateater", 
"Eesti Noorsooteater", "Rahvusooper Estonia", "Rakvere Teatrimaja", 
"Sakala Teatrimaja", "Vene Teater"), .rows = structure(list(1:3, 
    4:6, 7:8, 9:12, 13L, 14:17), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My colors:

```
prx_col_palette <- function(){
  c("#E69F00",
    "#56B4E9",
    "#009E73",
    "#F0E442",
    "#0072B2",
    "#D55E00",
    "#CC79A7")
}
prx_cols <- prx_col_palette()
```

My bubble chart:

```
ggplot(pindalad_joonisele,
       aes(x = str_to_title(hoone_liik), 
           y = str_to_title(reorder(asutus, desc(asutus))),
           colour = str_to_title(hoone_liik),
           size = hoone_suletud_netopind)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = hoone_suletud_netopind), 
            colour = "white", 
            size = 3.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top")+
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(13, 35)) + # Adjust as required.
  scale_colour_manual(values = prx_cols)+
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=11),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=11),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

I would like that the order of y and x axis would be as follows:

```
pindalad_joonisele$asutus <- factor(pindalad_joonisele$asutus, levels = c("Eesti Draamateater", "Eesti Noorsooteater",
                                                                          "Rahvusooper Estonia", "Rakvere Teatrimaja", "Sakala Teatrimaja",
                                                                          "Vene Teater"))

pindalad_joonisele$hoone_liik <- factor(pindalad_joonisele$hoone_liik, levels = c("teatrihoone", "ladu", "töökojad", "muu"))
```

However, nothing seems to work and they are in a reversed or random order. Can somebody please help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, I don't understand what this question is all about. I like the plot, it's simple to follow. In my opinion, the `ggplot's` `x` and `y` variables are incorrectly defined. Also added `scale_y_discrete(limits = rev)` to change the order top-to-bottom.

Sample code:

```
pindalad_joonisele$asutus <- factor(pindalad_joonisele$asutus, levels = c("Eesti Draamateater", "Eesti Noorsooteater",
                                                                          "Rahvusooper Estonia", "Rakvere Teatrimaja", "Sakala Teatrimaja",
                                                                          "Vene Teater"))

pindalad_joonisele$hoone_liik <- factor(pindalad_joonisele$hoone_liik, levels = c("teatrihoone", "ladu", "töökojad", "muu"))


ggplot(pindalad_joonisele,
       aes(x = hoone_liik, 
           y = asutus,
           colour = hoone_liik,
           size = hoone_suletud_netopind)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = hoone_suletud_netopind), 
            colour = "white", 
            size = 3.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top")+
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev) # reverse y axis
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(13, 35)) + # Adjust as required.
  scale_colour_manual(values = prx_cols)+
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=11),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=11),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

Plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The thing that bothered me was that with x and y variables defined with the str_to_title,  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev) did not work.